# Python Decimal division giving unexpected answer

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

I don't understand the logic behind Decimal division:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
```

This works perfectly:

```
>>> Decimal("11") / 2
 Decimal('5.5')
```

But this already not:

```
>>> Decimal("21") / 2
Decimal('10')
```

Why is it not "10.5"?...

Answer (score 0):

In your case this happened because of insufficient precision.
Value was rounded respectively to "rounding" property of Decimal context.

As described in python docs, decimal context precision come into play during arithmetic operations.
The precision determines accuracy for calculations. This means that you may have different results depending on value of the precision.

[Quote from python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

> Widely differing results indicate insufficient precision, rounding
>   mode issues, ill-conditioned inputs, or a numerically unstable
>   algorithm.

So the only thing that you have to do is to increase value of decimal precision.
By default it is equals 28.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal's context `prec` regards all digits in the numbers, not just the numbers after the decimal point.

So, `5.5`  has 2 digits, as have `10`. If you want to see `10.5` you have to set precision to 3 digits.